# How to mount a folder as a Drive and give it a label using command line in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, drive-letter

I have admin priviledges on my PC and using windows 11. I use this command lines to mount my local folder to a Drive letter & also trying to give a label :

```
subst z: c:\Users\andi\temp
label z: NEWNAME
```

the 'label command' give me error :

```
Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges or
the disk may be locked by another process.
You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode
and make sure the disk is unlocked.
```

How can I label it without admin privileges ? normally I can rename drive's label by right clicking the drive letter -> properties , then change the label easily. But this time , I mounted it without problem but denied when trying to label it.